# Python Pandas: convert DD.MM.YYYY to datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
date       | ...
09.01.2000 |
02.03.2001 | ...
```

The format is DD.MM.YYYY. I want to select only data where it is year 2014 (for example). I convert them into datetime using `pd.to_datetime`:

```py
date = pd.to_datetime(table["date"], format = "%d.%m.%Y")
```

Then I want my table to take 3 new columns `Day, Month, Year`. I do:

```py
table[["day", "month", "year"]] = date.dt.day, date.dt.month, date.dt.year
```

But it throws error: `Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray`
How do I convert them into datetime properly to use `df.loc[df["year"] == 2014]`?

Comment: You could also use `DataFrame.assign`: `table = table.assign(day=date.dt.day, month=date.dt.month, year=date.dt.year)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do manually:

```
table['day'], table['month'], table['year'] = date.dt.day, date.dt.month, date.dt.year
```

**Explanation**: `date.dt.day, date.dt.month, date.dt.year` is short hand for a tuple with length `3`, which is most likely different from `len(table)`.

On the other hand, since you already have `date`, you can also slice with:

```
table[date.dt.year==2014]
```

Comment: I thought it can do it once in a pythonic way. Thanks for your answer! I'll accept when it's allowed.

Comment: Maybe try split ?